# Incompatibility warnings after npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I used `npx create-react-app my-app`
but it show me error shown below. What should I do if expected to create a react project. The warnings below were occured.

```
C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\react>npx create-react-app reactapp

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 23 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-scripts@3.4.3
└─ react@16.13.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions@7.11.0
├─ ... some dependencies here ...
└─ webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
Done in 35.57s.
```

Comment: you should add some more info about your expectations. what is wrong there? have you tried to go to `/my-app/`  directory and then run `npm start`? If you won't add some more info, your question will get down votes!

Answer (score 1):

reinstall GIT and try again. my CREATE-REACT-APP was giving the same error and reinstalling git the error was resolved